# Laptop fans unexpectedly spin at full power

Tags: windows-8.1, fan, acer-aspire

I have an Acer Aspire V17 Nitro (VN7-791G), 
the almost 2-year old model, so the rip-off model in fact:
GTX-860 2GB, 16GB RAM, 1TB HDD, 256SSD, Intel Core i7-4710HQ. Hardware information:

[image: HARDWARE DATA]

My fans are just non-stop going on 100% power, then are normal for about 15 minutes, then go back to spinning again. My IT guy renewed my cooling gel on my GPU recently too to see if that was the problem, clearly not. Fans were cleaned out too, no effect either.

Before that there was the Windows 10 update which it did while my laptop was in sleep mode and closed. The misery that that brought... Windows 10 can't work with my two graphic drivers. So after formatting I went back to 8.1 Enterprise  and had to reinstall all my programs.

I use it in a room at about 18-22 °C. I don't have any demanding programs running.

My Panda Global Security doesn't detect any malware/viruses or spyware, there are no suspicious files, and programs are running fine. There's nothing in Task Manager or Resource Monitor that shouldn't be there. I just see in Resource Monitor that my frequency is always so high.

What should I do?

Comment: try Speedfan and look if you can define your own cooler profile and slow down the speed of the fan: http://www.almico.com/sfarticle.php?id=5

Comment: does Speedfan work for your Acer?

Comment: Haven't had the chance to try yet, had exams until yesterday